# What is the point of using view.getRootView().findViewById() inside of onViewCreated in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-lifecycle

I am watching a tutorial in which the instructor uses

```
test = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.test);
```

inside of onViewCreated() in the fragment.

So something like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //test is just a TextView for testing the application, will remove it later
        test = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.test);
    }
```

Is there any point of using `view.getRootView().findViewById()` opposed to just using `view.findViewById()`? I'm a little confused on the purpose of `getRootView()` here as the instructor uses.

Thank you!

Comment: At best, `view.getRootView()` would evaluate to `view`, and it's a wasted method call. At worst, the `test` widget is not a child of `view`, but rather lives somewhere else in the activity, and the instructor is reaching around to get it. That would be a very bad idea, particularly for some sort of training materials.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. The test widget is just the default TextView(the one that says, "Hello blank fragment") which comes with a blank fragment(I just changed the id to test). As a result, I guess it's just a wasted method call.  Would there be any use of calling view.getRootView in other scenarios? Thanks.

Comment: I can only imagine one scenario where i would want to do this. When you create a Fragment  inside a fragment which lives inside an activity and the activity holds views beside the fragment and you want to access a view inside the activity. If I am correct is the view you get the view of the fragment which created this childFragment, but you need access to the view at the root level(the activity). This is a scenario I can imagine, but I would never do this because i can't predict how this would behave in some cases I might construct.

Comment: I think it really depends on what the view is. If it's a _TextView_, say, you will just find the _TextView_.  If the view is a _ViewGroup_, you may be looking for a view that is above it in the hierarchy. For instance, a _LinearLayout_ contains a _TextView_ and a _RelativeLayout_ which contains an _ImageView_. Given the _ImageView_, how do you find the _TextView_? This is when _view.getRootView()_ can come in handy. Whether this applies to the exact circumstance of your instructions materials, is something you must determine.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you all!

Comment: @DominikWuttke The scenario you described is incorrect. When `onViewCreated()` is called, the `Fragment`'s `View` hierarchy **is not yet attached to its parent** (ie: the `Activity`'s `View`s), so it would not be possible to find other `View`s outside of the `Fragment`'s own `View`s in this way. See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you for the hint. I was referring to https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle 
"When your fragment reaches the CREATED state, it has been added to a FragmentManager and the onAttach() method has already been called."
It seems, this excludes the view parents.